# Concatenar duas funções! (MySQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho duas funções que fiz para exibir dados em uma tabela. Porém eu não estava conseguindo criar essa função em uma única função, então criei duas, porém, quando chamo as duas no "foreach" ela é exibida 4 vezes para cada dado.

Aqui está ambas as funções:

```
                public function getStockName()            
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `produtos`";
                $results = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query)  or die(mysqli_error());
                $stocks1 = array();
                while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) ) {
                    $stocks1[$result['idProdutos']] = $result['nome'];
                }
                mysqli_close($this->_con);
                return $stocks1;
            }

            public function getStockQuant()            
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `produtos`";
                $results = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
                $stocks2 = array();
                while  ( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) ) {
                    $stocks2[$result['idProdutos']] = $result['quantidade'];
                }
                mysqli_close($this->_con);
                return $stocks2;
            }
```

A primeira pega o "nome" da tabela "produtos" e a segunda pega a "quantidade" da tabela "produtos". Porém acabo tendo que criar 2 "foreach" para chamar as 2 funções, e exibe os dados 4 vezes na tabela.

Queria saber como concatenar essa função, ou se existe algum modo de chamar as duas funções em um "foreach".

Meu código php está mais ou menos assim:

```
    <?php               
    try {
    $user_A = new Cl_User();
    $stocks1 = $user_A->getStockName();
    if(empty($stocks1)){
    $_SESSION['error'] = NO_DATA;

    }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    header('Location: home.php');exit;
    }

    ?>
    <?php               
    try {
    $user_B = new Cl_User();
    $stocks2 = $user_B->getStockQuant();
    if(empty($stocks2)){
    $_SESSION['error'] = NO_DATA;

    }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    header('Location: home.php');exit;
    }

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form-estoque" role="form" id="estoque-produto">                             

    <center><h2>Estoque</h2></center>

    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Produto" title="Type in a name">

    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="header">
                <th style="width:20%;"><center>Nome</center></th>
                <th style="width:20%;"><center>Quantidade</center></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($stocks1 as $key=>$nome) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($stocks2 as $key=>$quantidade) { ?>
                <tr>

                    <td><center><?php echo $nome; ?></center></td>
                    <td><center><?php echo $quantidade; ?></center></td>

                </tr>
            <?php } ?>  <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia simplificar usando array associativo, isto apenas:

```
public function getStockName()            
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `produtos`";
    $results = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query)  or die(mysqli_error());
    $stocks = array();

    while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) ) {
        $stocks[$result['idProdutos']] = array(
            'nome' => $result['nome'],
            'quantidade' => $result['quantidade']
        );
    }

    mysqli_close($this->_con);
    return $stocks;
}
```

E para usar seria isto:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($stocks as $id => $stock) { ?>
        <tr>

            <td><center><?php echo $stock['nome']; ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $stock['quantidade']; ?></center></td>

        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isso que eu estava querendo, vai me ajudar nas próximas tabelas que vou fazer.

Só uma dúvida, porque ali no "foreach" você trocou o "$key" por "$id"? 
Sinceramente não sei para que servia o "$key" também, se puder explicar agradeço.

Comment: @Anonn o $key no seu código original é o ID de cada linha do seu banco, então nomeie para $id para ficar mais intuitivo.